# Help with adding a custom option type value field

Tags: product, adminhtml, admin, custom-options

I'm extending the catalog_product_option_type_value database. I created my own table, my_catalog_product_option_type_value and it has a reference to the option_type_id. I have that working, and my class working but I added a table column to the custom options grid and I can't figure out how to get my custom field value.

[image]

When I click the 'Save and Continue Button', I want to be able to get the ID of the newly created or existing option_type_id and then use that id and 'My Value' to insert or update a record into my my_catalog_product_option_type_value table. I created an observer that picks up the catalog_product_prepare_save event. That is working but it only returns a product and it's options. I can't get my value. I found this code in the ProductController class:

```
if (isset($productData['options']) && !$product->getOptionsReadonly()) {
        $product->setProductOptions($productData['options']);
    }
```

So, I though i'd be able to do something like

```
$productData['options']['my_value']
```

but that doesn't work because the post data is [options][id][values][id][my_value]. I don't know how i'd get the id of these options. So, I'm a little stuck and hoping someone can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you will have to do some array itterations and key checking to pull your values.

Try this in your observer.

```
$options = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getOptions();
if (is_array($options)) {
  foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
      if (is_array($option)  && array_key_exists('values',$option)) {   
          foreach ($option['values'] as $value) {
              if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists('YOUR FIELD NAME',$value)) {
                   $result = $value['YOUR FIELD NAME'];
                   // do something with the $result
              } 
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the catalog_product_prepare_save observer, you should use the code

> $options = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getProductOptions();

instead of

> $options = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getOptions();

& refer the remaining part in ProxiBlue's answer!

I tested it work with magento 1.8.1.0 version.